# Poor tree add performance

Tags: c++, tree, containers

I am writing a tree container at the moment (just for understanding and training) and by now I got a first and very basic approach to add elements to the tree.

This is my tree code by know. No destructor, no cleanup and no element access by now.

```
    template <class T> class set
    {
    public:
        struct Node
        {
            Node(const T& val)
                : left(0), right(0), value(val)
            {}

            Node* left;
            Node* right;
            T     value;
        };

        set()
        {}

        template <class T> void add(const T& value)
        {
            if (m_Root == nullptr)
            {
                m_Root = new Node(value);
            }

            Node* next    = nullptr;
            Node* current = m_Root;

            do
            {
                if (next != nullptr)
                {
                    current = next;
                }

                next = value >= current->value ? current->left : current->right;
            } while (next != nullptr);

            value >= current->value ? current->left = new Node(value) : current->right = new Node(value);
        }

    private:
        Node* m_Root;
    };
```

Well, now I tested the add performance against the insert performance of a std::set with unique and balanced (low and high) values and came to the conclusion that the performance is simple awful.

Is there a reason why the set inserts values that much faster and what would be a decent way of improving the insert performance of my approach? (I know that there might be better tree models, but as far as I know, the insert performance should be close together between most tree models).

under an i5 4570 stock clock,
the std::set needs 0.013s to add 1000000 int16 values.
my set need 4.5s to add the same values.

where does this big difference come from?

Update:

Allright, here is my testcode:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 1000000;
    test::set<test::int16> mset; //my set
    std::set<test::int16>   sset; //std set
    std::timer      timer;         //simple wrapper for clock()

    test::random_engine engine(0, 500000); //simple wrapper for rand() and yes, it's seeded, and yes I am aware that an int16 will overflow

    std::set<test::int16> values; //Set of values to ensure unique values

    bool flip = false;
    for (int i = 0; n > i; ++i)
    {
        values.insert(flip ? engine.generate() : 0 - engine.generate());
        flip = !flip; //ensure that we get high and low values and no straight line, but at least 2 paths
    }

    timer.start();
    for (std::set<test::int16>::iterator it = values.begin(); values.end() != it; ++it)
    {
        mset.add(*it);
    }
    timer.stop();

    std::cout << timer.totalTime() << "s for mset\n";

    timer.reset();

    timer.start();
    for (std::set<test::int16>::iterator it = values.begin(); values.end() != it; ++it)
    {
        sset.insert(*it);
    }
    timer.stop();

    std::cout << timer.totalTime() << "s for std\n";
}
```

the set won't store every value due to dubicates but both containers will get a high number and the same values in the same order to ensure representative results. I know the test could be more accurate but it should give some comparable numbers.

Comment: Did you used optimized build?

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot yes, full optimization

Comment: You should provide your test code. If you add unique values to your tree it will degenerate to a singly-linked list. So insert costs O(n) instead of O(log(n))

Comment: I see a bug. You continue with insertion even when the value was placed as a root. Probably not the performance bottleneck, but still...

Comment: @max basically I got a random generator and I am adding values to a seperate set (alternately n and 0 - n). Afterwards I am adding the values to my set measuring the time and then I add the values to a seperate std::set measuring the time to ensure both are working with the same values.

Comment: Could you, please, show us your testing code with a random generator? And it seems that your code is an implementation of a `multiset`, are you sure the numbers are unique?

Comment: @DAle yes, I am sure since I am using a std::set for unique numbers. (now an unordered_set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two obvious differences are:

1. the red-black tree (probably) used in `std::set` rebalances itself to put an upper bound on worst-case behaviour, exactly as DAle says.

   If this is the problem, you should see it when plotting N (number of nodes inserted) against time-per-insert. You could also keep track of tree depth (at least for debugging purposes), and plot *that* against N.
2. the standard containers use an allocator which probably does something smarter than `new`ing each node individually. You could try using [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) in your own container to see if that makes a significant improvement.

---

**Edit 1** if you implemented a pool allocator, that's relevant information that should have been in the question.

**Edit 2** now that you've added your test code, there's an obvious problem which means your set will always have the worst-case performance for insertion. *You pre-sorted your input values!* `std::set` is an ordered container, so putting your values in there first guarantees you always insert in increasing value order, so your tree (which does not self-balance) degenerates to an expensive linked list, and your inserts are *always* linear rather than logarithmic time.

You can verify this by storing your values in a `vector` instead (just using the `set` to detect collisions), or using an `unordered_set` to deduplicate without pre-sorting.

Comment: I already tried a pool allocator which preallocates all of the int16 for the tests. Sadly that did not fix the performance difference for the tree. I wrapped my int16 into a class wit an overloaded op new to ensure that the std::set is forced to use my allocator which improved the overall performance for both trees (std and my one) but the difference was still really big.

Comment: Well, the the pool allocator isn't in the test code anymore since it did not solve my issue, but I will try it without preordered values.

Comment: Okay, that's it, if I use an unordered set as value pool the difference disappears. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`std::set` implementation usually uses [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) data structure. It's a self-balancing binary search tree, and it's `insert` operation is guaranteed to be `O(log(n))` time complexity in the worst-case (that is required by the standard). You use simple binary search tree with `O(n)` worst-case insert operation.

If you insert unique random values, such a big difference looks suspicious. But don't forget that randomness will not make your tree balanced and the height of the tree could be much bigger than `log(n)`

**Edit**

It seems I found the main problem with your code. All generated values you store in `std::set`. After that, you add them to the sets in the increasing order. That's degrading your set to the linked list.

Comment: I tried a rb tree implementation. With this amount of values and the division between high and low, my tree implementation performs very similar to the std::set. But thanks anyway, I will switch to a rbtree.